# Cannot get class-files from Java-package in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, package-explorer

I have a webapp containing some Java-classes within some packages. However within Package-Explorer only the names of the packages are listed, but I cannot get the classes within them. Thus the icon for the package stays empty meaning there is no content within the package.

When I manually drag a class from the WinExplorer into the Package-Explorer I get a warning that the class is already contained in the package. Having said this the package is not empty, however I cannot get any of its classes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check Project-->Properties-->Java Build Path-->Sources tab.
Make sure that "Included" is properly set (Usually to "All").
Also check that the "[Filter](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-27.htm)" (little triangle icon) is not hiding the required code sources.
You can also try to "New-->Java Project" than use the existing sources.

Comment: Included is (by default) set to `All`, however, I cannot find the settings for this filter.

Comment: Strange, when I select "Empty packages" within the filter-setting all my packages are filtered out. However when I drag a class-file from WindExplorer to Project-Explorer I get the warning mentioned earlier indicating the package is NOT empty.